# Get Cell value of another column if string match found in a given column in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am doing string operation on a csv file using pandas. I want to retrieve the value of a cell from another column if a string match is found in a particular column

```
s1='a b'
a=['ab','bc','cd','gh']
b=['a b','cd','ef','']
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':a})
df['b']=b


if((df['a']==s1).any()):
    print("s1 exists") 
elif:
   (df['b']==s1).any())

   I want to get the cell value from df['a'] corresponding to the matching row in df['b'] i.e I expect to get the value 'ab' from df['a']
```

I am not sure how do i do it. Thanks

Comment: What's your expected output from the above example?

Comment: `df[df.b == s1].a`

Comment: @ATL I expect to get 'ab' from df['a']

Comment: @abhilb this works too. But the answer given by SammitR is complete. So have accepted it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for: using [`df.index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.index.html). Please do let me know if this clarifies your query.

```
if((df['a']==s1).any()):
    print("s1 exists in a") 
elif (df['b']==s1).any():
    print(df['a'][df.index[df['b']==s1].tolist()[0]])
```

Comment: Thanks @SammitR  I get the output as                                                                           0    ab
Name: a, dtype: object                                                                                                         I want only ab as the output

Comment: please check now. @Sid